# How to delete all nodes in doubly linked list?

Tags: go, doubly-linked-list

I'm curious as to what is the correct way of deleting all nodes in a doubly linked list.

Here's my linked list structure:

```
type ListNode struct {
    Data branch
    Next *ListNode
    Prev *ListNode
}

type doublyLinkedList struct {
    Head *ListNode
    Tail *ListNode
    Size int
}
```

Will it  work if I just point the Head & Tail nodes to Nil?

```
func deleteAllNodes(dl *doublyLinkedList) {
    dl.Head = nil
    dl.Tail = nil
    dl.Size = 0
}
```

If so, what happens to all the nodes? Does it get garbage collected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a reference counted environment (`Arc` in Rust, `shared_ptr` in C++, Swift, etc.), this could leak.

The nodes may have references among themselves, but there's no other references to them. In graph theory terms, the nodes being "deleted" form a component of the object graph, which is now a disconnected graph.

Any environment with a tracing garbage collector (including Go) can handle this, no problem.

First, the GC will detect all connected components of the memory graph (those objects which are referenced from root references, like global variables, local variables, etc.). This is called the "mark" phase. Then, it will delete all disconnected components in a second "sweep" phase. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tracing_garbage_collection#Na%C3%AFve_mark-and-sweep

Comment: I think you meant to say that in reference counter environments it could(!) leak. It really depends on how the adt is implemented. The first node could easily have no references pointing to it, thus getting freed and cascading to free the rest.

Comment: @DanielTrugman Not if the rest of the nodes have back-references to the nodes before them. A strong reference cycle could form, which would prevent the "cascade" from ever starting. In order for there to not be a leak, references can only be strong in one direction (typically from one node to the next), while the other needs to be a weak reference (typically from one node to its previous node)

Comment: Exactly. My point is, it might leak and might not, it depends on the implementation. I am definitely NOT encouraging to write that sort of code, but just making sure not to give the wrong impression.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Makes sense! I did already change "would" to "could". It was too strong a statement, "would" made it sound like it's impossible to write a memleak-free doubly link system with a ref counted system, which is certainly not the case haha